# Is there fundamental group "with coefficients"

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Constructing fundamental group in usual way, one uses $I=[0,1] \in \mathbb R$, so uses real numbers, and gets a group classifying coverings for nice spaces: locally connectible and so on, in fact spaces "with real properties". But one can also go the opposite way and define etalé fundamental group via coverings.

So the questions are

1. Whether there is a definition of, for example, etalé fundamental group for p-adic manifolds via "pathes" or something similar?
2. It seems that one can correctly define fundamental group verbatim, using an ordered 2-divisible abelian group, such as rational numbers, but does the result make sense?

Comment: Interesting question, but the title doesn't really fit, right?

Comment: I agree that the title doesn't fit. For example, the correct notion of "fundamental group with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients" is just $\pi_1(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ (for $\pi_1(X)$ nilpotent, say). This has nothing to do with considering paths using the rational interval, which I would anticipate gets you nothing interesting.